# How can I find the nth strange prime?

Tags: java, primes

My problem is:
Given a number n as input, return the value of the nth strange prime.Example-29 is a strange prime because it is a prime number and its sum of digits (reduced to a single digit) = 2+9 = 11 = 1+1 = 2 which is a prime number.
nthStrange(2) = 3
nthStrange(8) = 41

This is what I have done so far-

```
public class NthStrangePrime{

    static int testcase1=1;
    static int testcase2=6;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        NthStrangePrime testInstance=new NthStrangePrime();
        int result=testInstance.nThStrangePrime(testcase2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public int nThStrangePrime(int n){
        int count=0;
        int sum=0;
        int num=2;
        int s=0;
        while(count!=n){
            while(num>0){
                sum=sum+num%10;
                num=num/10;
            }
            while(sum>0){
                s=s+sum%10;
                sum=sum/10;
                //System.out.println(s);
            }
            int j=2;
            while(j<=s-1){
                if(s%j==0){
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }
            if(j==s){
                System.out.println("This is a Strange Prime :"+s);
                count++;
            }
            num=num+1;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

My problem is in second while loop.It is not working fine and I am unable to find out the problem.

Comment: maybe this is because of `sum=sum/10`, print this val to make sure about exact/desire value.

Comment: @parsaporahmad checked. That is working fine. I think problem is in the second while loop.

Comment: I think your second while loop will only produce the 11 in your example and not the 2. You need to do more iterations until it is only a single digit.

Comment: @DrLudwig3 Yes,that's what happening.But that part was working fine when I checked it in another program.But it is not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally good idea in programming, to seperate each logic part into seperate method (in more complex programs, you separate it into classes, components etc.).

Then you can easily test each logic part separately, it is more reusable (using already existing methods), it is much more userfriendly (you just look to it and you see, aah, here I am doing "sumDigit").

This is working code :

```
public class NthStrangePrime {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("29 is : " + isStrangePrime(29));
        System.out.println("13 is : " + isStrangePrime(13));
        System.out.println("14 is : " + isStrangePrime(14));
        System.out.println("15 is : " + isStrangePrime(15));
        System.out.println("16 is : " + isStrangePrime(16));
        System.out.println("17 is : " + isStrangePrime(17));

        System.out.println("13th strange number is : " + nThStrangePrime(13));
    }

    public static int nThStrangePrime(int n){
        int strangePrimes = 0;
        int number = 2;
        while (strangePrimes != n){
            if (isStrangePrime(number)){
                strangePrimes++;
                System.out.println("This is a Strange Prime :"+number);
            }
            number++;
        }
        return number-1;
    }

    public static boolean isStrangePrime(int n) {
        while ((n > 9) && (isItPrime(n))){
            n = sumDigit(n);
        }            
        if ((n <= 9) && (isItPrime(n))){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int sumDigit(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            sum += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static boolean isItPrime(int n) {
        if (n <= 1){
            return false;
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean isPrimeNumber = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                isPrimeNumber = false;
                break; // exit the inner for loop
            }
        }

        return isPrimeNumber;
    }
}
```

Output for this code :

```
29 is : true
13 is : false
14 is : false
15 is : false
16 is : false
17 is : false
This is a Strange Prime :2
This is a Strange Prime :3
This is a Strange Prime :5
This is a Strange Prime :7
This is a Strange Prime :11
This is a Strange Prime :23
This is a Strange Prime :29
This is a Strange Prime :41
This is a Strange Prime :43
This is a Strange Prime :47
This is a Strange Prime :61
This is a Strange Prime :83
This is a Strange Prime :101
13th strange number is : 101
```

Comment: Actually my code is working fine for checking the strange prime.But it is not working when I added the part of returning Nth strange prime.

Comment: @newbie - ok, I added the method for finding nth strange prime. Take my example not only as "now it works". I tried to give you valuable know-how and best-practices with an example :).

Comment: Thank you very much.With your help I'll be able to resolve the problems of my code.